# Sort dataframe by row index value without changing values

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, indexing

I have a dataframe that I have to sort in decreasing order of absolute row value without changing the actual values (some of which are negative).

To give you an example,  e.g. for the 1st row, I would like to go from
`-0.01189179 0.03687456 -0.12202753` to
`-0.12202753 0.03687456 -0.01189179`.
For the 2nd row from
`-0.04220260 0.04129326 -0.07178175` to
`-0.07178175 -0.04220260 0.04129326` etc.

How can I do this in R?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
lst <- lapply(df , \(x) order(-abs(x)))

ans <- data.frame(Map(\(x,y) x[y] , df ,lst))
```

- output

```
            a           b
1 -0.01189179 -0.07178175
2  0.03687456 -0.04220260
3 -0.12202753  0.04129326
```

- data

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(-0.12202753, 0.03687456, -0.01189179), b = c(-0.0422026, 
0.04129326, -0.07178175)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple approach (using @Mohamed Desouky's Data)

```
df <- df[nrow(df):1,]
```

```
> df
            a           b
3 -0.01189179 -0.07178175
2  0.03687456  0.04129326
1 -0.12202753 -0.04220260
```